# PHP class problems. Can't call another class?

Tags: php, class

I have a class file: class_xx.php. And then a function file: function_xxx.php

In my function_xxx.php:

```
require_once('class_xx.php')

... // after few next lines

$object = new class_xx1($arg1, $arg2);
```

But it gives me:

Fatal error: Class 'class_xx1' not found in "some_path" on line "1XX3"

[sorry I can't exposed the codes yet], any idea why I included the file > require_once with no error, but it gives me "Class not found error"??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are you misspelled the class declaration or something to that avail. You will what to double-check that your spell it the exact same way, with the same casing.

If you are developing on a secondary sever, you might have not transferred the completed `class_xxx.php` file over and just a blank file, in which case PHP would be including a blank file.

By the way, you forgot a semi-colon after the `require_once`

Comment: Ops, I forgot the semi-colon in this question. I try to re-transfer that file. But I could open the file in my server and its not blank.

Comment: Arggg... stupid server. After I re-transfer the file, it works now. Thanks. Please close this thread as I think is useless now. No programming related. But if u wish to keep it, I respect your decision. Anyway, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly, the `class_xx.php` does not correctly declare the `class_xx1` class. Review your code and watch for typos. Put some sort of debug line like `echo "hello;` in the required file if you want to be sure that it is being included correctly.

Comment: Double check the typos, class name, everything is fine. Irritating